# raspberry piのクロスコンパイル環境

Tags: raspberry-pi

http://qiita.com/atchy@github/items/fb9df9e5865d8c7f7a72

こちらのサイトでraspbianのクロスコンパイル環境を作り方が説明されているのですが、Ubuntuのbit数はraspbianと合わせた方がいいのでしょうか？
raspbianは
Linux raspberrypi 3.18.11+ #781 PREEMPT Tue Apr 21 18:02:18 BST 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux
これを使用しています。
armv6lが何bitなのか分からないのですが、32bitまたは64bitのどちらに合わせた方がいいでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: [ARM architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) によれば ARMv6 は `32bit` ですね。

Comment: そう言えば以前の質問でコメントした、[Installing FFMPEG for Raspberry Pi](http://www.jeffreythompson.org/blog/2014/11/13/installing-ffmpeg-for-raspberry-pi/) のインストール方法では上手く行かなかったのでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
教えて頂いた方法でやったらffplay error 1がでました、、、
Raspbianにffmpegを入れるのにToolchainが必要と教えてもらったので、そちらを試しているところです。
それにラズパイでのコンパイルは時間がかかるのでクロスコンパイルの環境を整えようとしてます。

Answer (score 1):

クロスコンパイル環境ですからホストとターゲットのビット数が同じである必然はまったくありません。
むしろ 64bit/32bit の両方で問題の生じないソースコードが書けるように
ホストは 64bit のほうが良い、んぢゃないですかね？
ホスト側の 64bit native compiler と
クロス用の 32bit cross compiler と、
両方で [raspberry-pi](/questions/tagged/raspberry-pi) の 32bit コードをコンパイルしてみると違う警告が出たりします。